# Preventing line breaks in japanese text with word joiner

Tags: html

I'm having a div with Japanese text with two words as described below and I want to prevent a line breaks in between them.

```
<div>全界</div>
```

I have tried using a unicode word joiner between them, `&#8288;`, but it only seems to print a square and does not prevent a line break.

```
<div>全&#8288;界</div>
```

Result: 全⁠界

Anyone who could share some insights on this?

Comment: I actually did not see the line break... https://jsfiddle.net/dvg9nfok/ how can you have the line break?

Answer (score 1):

Your result doesn't show any line break between those 2 characters.

Although to prevent linebreaks use `white-space:nowrap`

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div>全界</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your div in `nobr`

```
<nobr><div>全界</div></nobr>
```

Comment: According to the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nobr) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr), this element is non-standard and [non-conforming](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) and should not be used. The alternative is the CSS declaration `white-space:nowrap;` (["white-space" documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)).